# Fedora 32 Immediate Wake-up after Suspend

Tags: linux, fedora, swap, suspend

**Description:**
On my machine, after I clicked "Suspend", when the system goes completely dark, it will always automatically wake up in 1-2 seconds. No data or status loss but I just can't get it into a normal suspend (I find the word "insomnia" best describes the situation).
Suspend is so important for me because sometimes late in the night I have my work still yet to finish but I would love to continue in the morning and I really wanna start from exactly where I stopped last night. Leaving the machine on all night would be so power-consuming for me...

**System Specs:**
OS: Fedora 32 (Workstation Edition)
Kernel: 5.8.16-200.fc32.x86_64
GNOME: 3.36.7

CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970X
Motherboard: Gigabyte TRX40 AORUS Xtreme
GPU: AMD Radeon Pro W5700
RAM: Thermaltake TOUGHRAM 64GB (8GBx8) DDR4 4000MHz (62.7 GiB according to my OS)
Disk: Samsung 970 EVO Plus 500GB nvme + Lexar 500GB nvme
LVM Configuration (name changed for better understanding):

```
LV    VG       LSize
root  Lexar    <336.76g
swap  Lexar    <127.40g
home  Samsung  <465.76g
```

**Outputs & Logs:**

*$ swapon -s*

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   133586940   0   -2
```

*$ journalctl -f* then *$ systemctl suspend -i*
[Log file on my OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmpwnFKtLhL_kPJApduCz7HACBnVWw)
(Too large to paste the whole log here)

**PS**
If there is any other information that could help you guys diagnose the problem, please please tell me and I would be so happy to provide. Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if your issue is similar to this [udev rule power wakeup configuration issue](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=110492).

Comment: @rickhg12hs : I did notice that I have 3 usb devices set to be "enabled" for wakeup. However, after I set them all to "disabled" the problem still exists. Thank you for helping me anyway.

Comment: Investigating my own issue.  BTW the code is `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep 'enabled'` in case anyone else needs it.  Still seeing a problem I can view in `journalctl` though even with USB disabled, and only `PWEB` and `SLPB` left enabled..  Also could not find reference for those besides someone commenting elsewhere `lspci`, although don't think that applies with those..